# Custompattern condition not working in repeating table second row infopath

Tags: infopath

**Repeating table columns**

[image]

Weight column is decimal(double) data type with two decimal places

In submit button click i set validation for not accepting string values in weight field.

```
Weight - does not match pattern - [0-9]*\.*[0-9]* (custom pattern)
```

this condition work for first row weight column but in second row if enter string value above validation not checked.

[image]

how to resolve this issue. I'm using infopath 2013 and share point 2013
.